# change color of the placeholder depending on the css class attached

Tags: html, css

I have forms in multiple places in the same html file.

I would like to have different colors for placeholders in different places.
I tried to attach css class to input field called form1 to change the color for it.

## I tried this:

```
.form1 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.form1 input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #000 !important;  
}

.form1 input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #000 !important;  
}

.form1 input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #000 !important;  
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc !important;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #ccc !important;  
}

input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #ccc !important;  
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #ccc !important;  
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

## html

```
 <form action="#" method="post" id="form2">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME" />
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" />
   <textarea rows="5" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
 </form>

 <form action="#" method="post" id="form1">
   <input class="form1" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
   <input type="submit" class="subscribe_btn" value="SUBSCRIBE" />
 </form>
```

both of them gives same `color : #ccc`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: @pavger Chrome browser

Comment: @sol I have added HTML to my question

Comment: `form1` is an ID. In your CSS you are targetting a class. Not sure that's the issue but worth fixing

Comment: Seems to be the issue actually -- https://jsfiddle.net/564vrb0a/

Comment: @sol it solved it. I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form1` is an ID. In your CSS you are targetting a class.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/564vrb0a/)

```css
#form1 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000 !important;
}

#form1 input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #000 !important;
}

#form1 input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #000 !important;
}

#form1 input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000 !important;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc !important;
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #ccc !important;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #ccc !important;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc !important;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form2">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME" />
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" />
  <textarea rows="5" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
</form>

<form action="#" method="post" id="form1">
  <input class="form1" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
  <input type="submit" class="subscribe_btn" value="SUBSCRIBE" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form2">
```

You are setting the id to form2. You need to set the class to form2 i.e. class="form2".

```
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #ccc !important;  
}
```

The !important flags are making these a priority. It's bad practice to select the same element with overlapping !important flags. Try removing them from the input selectors.